# getimagesize() for JPX returning null

Tags: php, image, null, getimagesize

When run the getimagesize() method on jpx images, I get nothing (no result, null).

It works fine for any other file type. Any ideas?

Just doing something simple like:

```
$info = getimagesize("bfx_10302003.jpx");
var_dump($info);
```